# Xamarin iOS app displaying white blank screen on iPad after update to Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xamarin, ipad

I have a **Xamarin.iOS** app developed on **Visual Studio 2019** and paired to a **Mac**. The app was displaying correctly on both **iPhones** and **iPads** until I updated **Xcode** on the **Mac** to ***version 11***. Since then **Apple** is rejecting my app because is displaying a white blank screen on **iPads** (see image below!).

I have validated the issue on **Xcode Simulator** and on a physical **iPad**. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

[image: ipad white blank screen on launch]

Comment: I would suggest you add the stacktrace and the output window details, it should help you find the cause

Comment: It may be because Apple deprecated the use of a LaunchImage asset catalog and you instead now have to use a LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you, and even though it could be you already got a solution i will share how i got it working at the end... for those who could still have that same problem.

**Note: in my case the issue appeared only on Apps built with XCode 11 that use `MasterDetailPage` on Xamarin.Forms version < 4.0 and running on iPad: the easiest solution to this issue is simply updating Xamarin.Forms to the latest version (or simply downgrading XCode to a previous version!), but if you (as i was) are not able to update Xamarin.Forms, then keep reading.**

---

As mentioned in [this thread from the Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/170757/ios-13-0-broke-masterdetailpage-on-ipads) all you have to do is copy the latest MasterDetailPage renderer from the [Xamarin.Forms source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabletMasterDetailRenderer.cs) and do a few changes.

Since the final script is too long to be added here as text (it exceeds the maximal number of allowed lines), and since i could not find a way to upload a text file, i would point to the thread in Xamarin Forums where i added that script with all the changes needed:

[TabletMasterDetailRenderer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/392427/#Comment_392427)

Note: Do not forget to change `{YourNamespace}` for your correct namespace!

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in at least Xamarin Forms 3.6.0.709228.